# Changing fonts for a section of the document

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I'm looking for an example of changing the font for just **one** TikZ node (in a picture).
I tried `[font=\augie]` but a big part of problem is that I can not find how to to load the font in the document. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (current page.center) [font=\augie] {$2+2=4$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What is `\augie` supposed to be? A font?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: yes, it is a hand-written font, I just installed it using Tex Live but don't know how to access it. The blackboard beamer theme uses it but I don't want to change the whole document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`augie` is only a textfont:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\def\augie{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (current page.center) {\augie foo $2+2=4$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\node at (current page.center) [font=\augie]{ foo $2+2=4$};
```

is also possible.